Is there any good reason to use C (<cstdio>) style code in C++ programs?
I've seen some programs where they mix C and C++ code in a single C++ program (even in coding interviews).
As far as I know all types of problems can be solved and developed using C++ alone, so I wonder if there's cases where one would need to introduce C code into your program through the <cstdio> library?

cstdio is a C++ library, meant to mirror the C library stdio.h. The question as it stands is probably too broad, but yes there is.

If you want to use the modern <print>, you are indirectly using a <cstdio> std::FILE (stdout). Or you can use it directly: std::println(stderr, "Error code {}", code);

Things that come to mind: iostream has its problems but is largely solved by fmt::print and later std::print. FILE struct is not interconvertible to fstream in anyway and in many API the former is required. C++26 filestream::native_handle may help solve part of the problem.

C IO may be faster than C++ streams. Although generally I'd say people teach C and then "C with classes" instead of teaching C++ - and such students tend to use what they know.

I have the reverse - a reason to not use it. If the programmer assumes that only <iostream> will be used, they may put ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false) into the program, which makes <iostream> faster but breaks <cstdio>.

At the beginning of C++ there was only c library. STL was introduced in 1994 and still didn't have lots of features, so lots of C library headers has mirrors in c++ in form with "c" prefix. So now <cstdio> is still here more for historical reason (and backward compatibility) then as a necessity. As point above out iostream turn out to be to clunky and C++23 has std::print (fmt moved to standard library).

@PiotrSiupa sync_with_stdio(false) does not break <cstdio>. It just means that you cannot arbitrarily interleave C++ IO and C IO operations on the same streams without explicitly flushing them in between.

This kind of programming is usually only found in competitive coding. It should not really be a technical problem because of backward compatibility with "C" (and that's the reason "C" is still avalable). But it is not recommended to write new code using "C" headers at all. Watch this Stop teaching "C" and read the C++ core guidelines. If you understand those guidelines, use that info in interviews :)

This is clearly not opinion-based -- there are a host of good objective reasons.

I prefer FILE IO with unique_ptr and <print>/<format> over <iostream>; Although MSVC has deprecated some  ISO C++ functions, and I need to add a predefined macro to circumvent it.

@PepijnKramer - in addition to competitive coding, it is used almost exclusively in embedded programming as well for the memory footprint benefit.

The calculation part, such as output or input in C++, has a larger memory footprint than the output or input in C.
Therefore, when trying to use optimization methods that reduce the amount of computation and reduce memory usage, libraries such as <cstdio> are used.
C++: cout<< val << endl;
C: printf("%d", val);
cout is an object class variable, and when output, it consumes as much memory as the object along with the class call.
However, printf consumes only the needs of the val variable.

"However, "printf" consumes only the capacity of the val variable." On most systems there is also some kind of object for stdout; it's simply not as visible to the user. I doubt that this would be meaningful reason to choose one over another on modern hosted systems.

cout is a global object. It may be the size of a class, but there is only 1 instance of it. All statements using cout will share a single instance, so that is hardly a factor in reducing output memory.

C++ is mostly compatible with C for a good reason: you can reuse existing C code in your C++ program easily.
If you have some algorithm implementation which prints useful info with printf, just compile and run it to get results. Just like you don't need to translate the algorithm's implementation to another language, you don't have to port the printf mini-language to C++ syntax. In addition, if you do minor changes to this "legacy" implementation, which syntax will you use for new messages? You might prefer printf syntax to make the code look more uniform.

Specifically about iostream syntax, there is some criticism which suggests that printf syntax is better (e.g. strings are more easily readable; no rarely-needed "locale" overhead at run-time). So maybe you should use std::format syntax if you can (C++20), or stick with printf if you can't yet.
